# What is stopping users from being inserted into the table?

Tags: python, syntax, sqlite

Whilst coding the section of my project which saves to a database, I couldn't seem to find the right way to get the data to insert to the table.
What should change/fix to get the variable to function with SQLite3?
Sidenote - the elements I am trying to insert come directly from a list. The variable `sqluserrequest` represents a single element of the list, formatted as a string.

Right now, i'm getting this syntax error:

```
line 42, in updatetable
    """, (sqluserrequest,))
OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error
```

As of the this post, I have tried calling the element I need directly from the list I.E. `usertags[y]`, where y increments to collect every individual element from the list, which traces back to:

```
line 33, in updatetable
    VALUES(?)""", (usertags[y]))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

I've also tried changing the tuple to a list literal, however this has little effect:

```
line 42, in updatetable
    """, [sqluserrequest])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error
```

I've also looking into string formatting, but this didn't seem to help.

sqluserrequest = the discordid(list element) to be saved

Here's the SQL scripts:

```
cursor.executescript("""
    CREATE TABLE Users(
    discordid VARCHAR (37) PRIMARY KEY,
    time VARCHAR (5)
    );
    """) #create 

update.execute(""" 
    INSERT INTO Users(discordid)
    VALUES(?)""", (sqluserrequest,)) #insert


update.execute("""
        UPDATE Users
        SET time = time + 1
        WHERE name = VALUES(?)
        """, (sqluserrequest,)) #update
```

The cursor changes between them, but as far as i'm aware that shouldn't affect the program since it is done at different connection points.

The intention of the script is to save a single string in discordid, and to update the element time that corresponds to the discord id by 1.
By changing the variable around, I have received only SQL errors above, but the closest the program has been to working is around these 'near VALUES syntax' errors. Is anyone able to see my mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have SQL syntax error here:

```
update.execute("""
    UPDATE Users
    SET time = time + 1
    WHERE name = VALUES(?)
    """, (sqluserrequest,)) #update
```

which you should just say `WHERE name = ?`

And for this error:

```
line 33, in updatetable
    VALUES(?)""", (usertags[y]))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

You pass in the SQL parameters wrong. It needs to be a tuple (or list) but you just put in a value in paretheses. The right right to specify a tuple with one item is `(usertags[y],)` with the extra comma.

Comment: Thank you, I've made these changes to the update statement and changed the parameter to a tuple, however now I have an unsupported data type error.

`InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`

Comment: @Dandy so the error said it. You need to check if `usertags[y]` is something supported and understood by the sqlite library. For instance, passing a random object will usually not work as sqlite library has no idea how to present it in C (as sqlite API is written in C).

Comment: All fixed! I ensured the data type was something C accepts, then I changed the expected data type in the create table script from INTEGER to INT. Thank you for your responses @adrtam